# How to zero all tuple values apart from the minimum and maximum values

Tags: python, tuples, max, min

I am trying to find the minimum and maximum values of a certain tuple and initialize all other values to zero

Say I have a tuple  p = (1,2,3)
Then p_new will be: (1,0,3)

I am trying to do this in a simple and elegant way without success

As of now, this is the implementation:

```
p = (1,2,3)

# finding the min/max indexes:
mx = p.index(max(p))
mn = p.index(min(p))

p_new = []
for i in range(len(p)):
    if i == mx:
        p_new.append(p[mx])
    elif i == mn:
        p_new.append(p[mn])
    else:
        p_new.append(0)
print('p_new is:',tuple(p_new))enter code here
```

The code output:

```
p_new is: (1, 0, 3)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: working fine for me!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
p = (1,2,3)
p = tuple( i if i in [min(p), max(p)] else 0 for i in p )

print('p_new is:',tuple(p_new))
```

Comment: Good answer, but you don't need the `[]` - `tuple` will accept a generator expression, so the list isn't needed.

Comment: Worth noting: It's better to save the min and max values in a variable before the new-tuple loop, instead of `[min(p), max(p)]` which is _re-_ calculated every iteration of the loop. It becomes _very slow_ for larger iterables, like `p = tuple(range(10_000))`. On my quite old machine, `%timeit tuple( i if i in [min(p), max(p)] else 0 for i in p )` is 4.37 **seconds** and `%timeit tuple( i if i in (mn, mx) else 0 for i in p )` is 1.59 **ms**. That's so **2748x** slower. PS. doing `minmax = min(p), max(p)` and `if i in minmax` is the fastest.